# SFDC Apex and JavaScript execution synchronization

Tags: apex, javascript

I have some queries on Apex and JavaScript execution. I want to insert large data to Salesforce after reading the file in JavaScript function and then I want to call the Apex method to insert the data chunk to the database. What I want to know is that how do I stop the execution of JavaScript further until I get the response from Salesforce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use asynchronous calls. Without using a library, that looks like this:

```
function sendData(data) {
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open('POST','/services/data/v35.0/sobjects/Account');
    x.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(this.readyState === 4) {
            // Process data, then...
            if(data.length) {
                sendData(data);
            }
        }
    };
    x.send(data.shift()); // send the next record
}
```

The exact nature of what you you need to do will depend on the framework. If you're using @RemoteAction methods, for example, you can do your next callback in the success handler.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As a newbie, I am learning the Web development and also I forgot to mention that the data file is in the format of XLSX.

Comment: You're going to have a very hard time reading xlsx files into JavaScript. I suggest you sick with something easier, like csv files.